# how to add multiple lines which are an array of the same parameter in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to pass an array of the same element, but i want them to be passed as new fields. I want to do something like:

```
        @POST("/api/userInfo/changeProfileData/")
        void updateProfile(
        @Field("userInfoProfile[languages][0]") String language1,
        @Field("userInfoProfile[languages][1]") String language2,
        Callback<BaseModel<StateModel>> callback);
```

But the problem is that i don't know the number of elements so i cannot do like above.

I tried to pass a list:

```
           @Field("userInfoProfile[languages]") List<String> languages
```

but the value is not valid because i need fields with their index (userInfoProfile[languages][0]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FieldMap](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/FieldMap.html) to make field association more dynamic.

Update your interface to:

```
 void updateProfile(
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> languages,
        Callback<BaseModel<StateModel>> callback);
```

Method that will build `FieldMap` out of your list

```
private Map<String, String> buildFieldMap(List<String> data){
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      String fieldName = "userInfoProfile[languages][%d]"
      for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
         map.put(String.format(fieldName, i), data.get(i));
     }
   return map;
}
```